# Triviality of finite fiber bundles

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology, tag-removed

Hello,

I suspect the following is true and easy but I am unable to prove. Suppose (E, B, π, F) is a fiber bundle, where E,B are compact and F is **finite**, prove that E is a trivial fiber bundle. Any help will be be greatly appreciated! If needed it is OK to assume E,B are locally path connected.

Comment: what is your definition of a fiber bundle? If it's the usual one, it encompasses covering spaces, and they can very well have finite fiber and be non trivial.

Comment: The level of this question is really borderline.  Perhaps you should ask at http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

This shouldn't be true unless you're using a different definition of fiber bundle than I would expect.

Consider the map $S^1 \to S^1$ which maps $z \mapsto z^2$. This is a fibre bundle whose fiber is a two-point set, but the base and total space are connected, and so the bundle is not trivial.